# Best way to display MySql data in Tkinter GUI

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, user-interface, tkinter

Just wondering if there is a better way to display MySql data to users of my app.

Basically I store look-up data then put it in a pop-up window for viewing:

```
    for row in all_reinforcement_data:
        r_total = ("Total number of reinforcement entries", mycursor.rowcount)
        r_id = ("\n\nId", row[0])

 messagebox.showinfo("Reinforcement Data Results", r_total + r_id)
```

Which doesn't look too polished but gives me what I want:

[image]

Is there any other ways of showing the user the data. In some form they could copy and paste from, ideally an excell spreadsheet or something similar.

Comment: You might want to read some of the content on tkdocs.com - it has examples of most of the widgets available in tkinter.

Comment: This question already has answers here:[pretty-print-data-in-tkinter-label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658656)

Comment: You can try `ttk.Treeview`.

Comment: @stovfl I don't think that really answers the question: as far as I can tell OP is asking for the data to be copy+pasteable

Comment: @Minion3665 This is a comment only. Let the OP decide if the given link is helpful or not. ***asking for the data to be copy+pasteable***: It isn't clear for me what the OP want to do here?

Comment: I settled for a combination; Exporting the data to excel with pandas so the user has the option to manipulate it later and having a new window pop up with read only information for instant reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a messagebox I don't believe you could do it. You could attempt to do it in a normal window with an entry that you could only copy out of, similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602106/in-pythons-tkinter-how-can-i-make-a-label-such-that-you-can-select-the-text-wi).

For example, you could do this to show the rows in a simple window:

```py
from tkinter import *
```

```py
row_info = Tk()
row_info.title("Reinforcement Data Results")

title = Label(text="Total number of reinforcement entries:")
title.pack()

data = Entry(row_info, borderwidth=0, justify='center')
data.insert(END, mycursor.row_count)
data.pack()

data.configure(state="readonly")

close = Button(row_info, text="Ok", command=row_info.destroy)
close.pack()

row_info.mainloop()
```